# DB not returning response

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am using Spring + Hibernate. Below is the Code snippet from my java method. After issuing query it is waiting for long time. Table size is very small. And it is occurring intermittently(not always). I do not face any exception. could you please let me know how to debug this issue.

Code Snippet:

```
BigDecimal id = null;
id = (BigDecimal) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<Object>() {
    public Object doInHibernate(Session session)throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    Query roleDetails = session.createSQLQuery("select role_id from employee where emp_id = '"+eid+"'");
                    return roleDetails.uniqueResult();
}
});
```

Comment: How long does it take? Time it using System.currentTimeInMillis() and also verify it by executing the same query through SQLDeveloper.

Comment: the query is very simple. It is taking only few millisecond if I running in TOAD. Issue is intermittent.

Comment: You might want to do an SQL EXPLAIN plan on the query as well.

Answer (score 0):

With the given details it is hard to understand what could be the root cause of the issue. I would suggest two things

1. Proxy your datasource and see the query execution time from java end. You can do this by using the [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy) library.
2. Trace [oracle](http://tinky2jed.wordpress.com/technical-stuff/oracle-stuff/what-is-the-correct-way-to-trace-a-session-in-oracle/) [sessions](http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_trace.htm) and [understand](http://www.gokhanatil.com/2011/05/tracing-oracle-sessions.html) if there is something wrong at the oracle side.

Answer (score 0):

Caching exists for queries both within Hibernate and within Oracle, but it only works properly when using prepared statements with parameters, otherwise it can hurt instead.

Try changing the string concatenation in your code to a parameterized query:

```
Query roleDetails = session.createSQLQuery("select role_id from employee where emp_id = ':empId").setInteger("empId", eid);
```